# RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand doesn't execute for CollectionView on iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, maui, infinite-scroll

I set up an infinite scrolling logic on a `CollectionView` where `IsGrouped = True`. It works as expected on Android, but from the very beginning it never worked on iOS, Windows and MacCatalyst (as the command doesn't execute at all on these platforms). Now data to retrieve from the cloud for my application are becoming massive and I can't afford loading everything at once in my collection anymore.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue? Or (if this is just a bug) is there any workaround I can apply to avoid setting a button to load pages one by one?

Here's the XAML code:

```
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="3"
        VerticalOptions="Fill">

        <CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemsGroup}"
            SelectionMode="Single"                   
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            RemainingItemsThreshold="2"
            RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
            IsGrouped="True">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue that being tracked in the links below, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10078

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13391

The command `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand` only works on Android but does not work on iOS or Windows, i.e. Scrolling has no effect and a breakpoint set in the Command `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand` is never being called.

Comment: I understand. Still, this is a show stopper for my app. Is there anything I can do to force the command to be fired? Consider that the workaround provided in those threads isn’t working in my case, because the `LogicalChildren` are someway to many and the `if` statement to execute the command is never hit.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware Thanks for the response, you can work around by placing a button binding to `LoadMoreItemsCommand` underneath the `CollectionView` for now referring to [CollectionView RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8338#issuecomment-1338049785). Also, you may need to wait for github thread's update to get the issue fixed all at once.